# WildFly 20.0.0.1 JAX-RS Resource not found

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, wildfly

I have the following REST Application:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import application.interfaces.ApplicationContext;

@ApplicationPath("/restapi/*")
public class TestRestAPIContext extends Application {
    @EJB
    private ApplicationContext ejbApplicationContext;

    @PostConstruct
    public void onInit() {
        try {
            System.out.println("REST INIT!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(TestRestAPIEndpoint.class));
    }
}
```

And the following REST Resource:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import engine.annotations.RestAPIMethod;

@Stateless
@Path("/endpoint")
public class TestRestAPIEndpoint {
    @GET
    @Path("/testme")
    @RestAPIMethod
    public String testAPI() {
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

All comes packaged in a .ear application with the following application.xml descriptor (META-INF/application.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd" version="7">
  <display-name>application-framework-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>application-framework-web.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/application-framework</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>application-framework-ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <library-directory>libs</library-directory>
</application>
```

And I have the following jboss-web.xml (application-framework-web.war/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/application-framework</context-root>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/application-framework-ds</res-ref-name>

        <jndi-name>java:/jdbc/datasource</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

And I have the following web.xml (application-framework-web.war/WEB-INF/web.xml):

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
<!--<servlet>-->
<!--<servlet-name>engine.TestRestAPIContext</servlet-name>-->
<!--<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>-->
<!--</servlet>-->

<!--<servlet-mapping>-->
<!--<servlet-name>engine.TestRestAPIContext</servlet-name>-->
<!--<url-pattern>/restapi/*</url-pattern>-->
<!--</servlet-mapping>-->
    <resource-ref>
        <description>Application Framework Datasource</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/application-framework-ds</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

**Please note:** Servlet in web.xml has been commented since I would like to use only annotations.

On Wildfly-20.0.0.1 i can see the following:

> RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class
> engine.TestRestAPIContext RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource
> engine.TestRestAPIEndpoint from Application class
> engine.TestRestAPIContext

Resource TestRestAPIEndpoint is never invoked. Furthermore, the @PostConstruct method of my TestRestAPIContext is not called. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Looking at your configuration, are your REST endpoints in a JAR? They need to be in a WAR is why I ask.

Comment: Yes, they are in a WAR, which is inside an EAR package.

Comment: Your path should be; /application-framework/restapi/endpoint/testme. If that is what you're using, try changing the value of the `@ApplicationPath` to `restapi` leaving off the `/*` as that is required to be appended by the implementation.